# Vigenere Cipher List Processing

Tags: python, list, loops, encryption, vigenere

So, I'm making my own Vigenere cipher program in Python and I've come as far as having two lists; one is a list with the ASCII numbers of the message to be encrypted/decrypted and the other is the same length and contains the ASCII numbers of the cipher key repeated. To add these two lists together I used this line of code:

```
encryption =  [x + y for x, y in zip(msglist, keylist)]
```

This works but I want the loop to ignore ASCII numbers that are not part of the alphabet but I have no idea how I can do this. I tried doing something like:

```
encryption =  [if chr(x).isalpha() != True: x + y for x, y in zip(msglist, keylist)]
```

but the syntax is invalid! What do I need to do to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you still want to include the digit characters but not encrypted, use the Python variant on a [ternary if](https://docs.python.org/3.3/faq/programming.html#is-there-an-equivalent-of-c-s-ternary-operator):

```
[x + y if chr(x).isalpha() else x for x, y in zip(msglist, keylist)]
```

If you want to ignore them entirely, use the [if part of list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
[x + y for x, y in zip(msglist, keylist) if chr(x).isalpha()]
```

Answer (score 1):

You have `ord(chr)`, the numbers in your list so check if `x <128`.

```
[x + y for x, y in zip(msglist, keylist) if x < 128]
```

**Test**:

```
>>> chr(222)
'\xde'
>>> chr(222).isalpha()
False
>>> 222 < 128
False
>>>
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm a beginner at Python and I don't quite understand what you mean